# 2 matrices of different sizes: if condition in matrix one is true, then do operation in matrix two

Tags: matlab

following problem I need to solve:
I have two matrices A and B ( A = 480x640 ; B = 40x40). 
For further explanation I take smaller matrices, because I think there is no difference for the logic, i.e.:

```
A = [1111; 1111; 1111; 1111];
B = [0 1; 1 0];
```

Each Element of B is the correspondence to 4 elements of matrix A.
For example:

```
B(1,1) = A(1:2,1:2)
```

If an element of B has a certain value, then i want do to some calculation in the correspondent elements of A.
so I want something like this:

```
[N M] = size(A);
[O P] = size(B);

for i = 1:O
for j = 1:P

if B(i,j) > 0;

for k = 1:N
for l = 1:M  

"DO CALCULATIONS " in A(k:k+1,l:l+1)

end
end
```

Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do something along the lines of what you want with this. The inner part of the nested for loops will return the "submatrix" that you are looking for

```
A = [1 2 3 4; 2 3 4 1; 3 4 1 2; 4 1 2 3];
B = [0 1; 1 0];

rowScale = size(A,1)/size(B,1);
colScale = size(A,2)/size(B,2);

assert(floor(rowScale) == rowScale & floor(colScale) == colScale,'Row and Column Sizes must be integer multiples')

for i = 0:size(B,1)-1
   for j = 0:size(B,2)-1
       if B(i+1,j+1) > 0
           subMatrix = A(i*rowScale+1:(i+1)*rowScale,j*colScale+1:(j+1)*colScale)
           % Do whatever calculations you need to do
       end
   end
end
```